# Mini cart drop down not appearing

Tags: magento2, cart, mini-cart

I have some issues on Magento 2.3.5 mini cart dropdown is not appearing.
Total number of products added in cart appearing but when I click on the mini cart it shows a black transparent overlay and nothing appears.
[image]

Comment: Check-in console of the browser if you got any error message.

Comment: Issue reolved basically i was trying to hide some content using display:none property of below `div` and it effected the minicart and disabled mini cart also. `<div class="message info empty"><div class="">We can't find products matching the selection.</div></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue reolved basically i was trying to hide some content in Magento calue theme using `display:none` property of below div and it effected the minicart and disabled mini cart also. `<div class="message info empty"><div class="">We can't find products matching the selection.</div></div>`